# Keeping CSS and jQuery animation responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

**My problems:**

- My animation is not responsive. Images and text move around and get too big when used on smaller screens.
- My .moveup class will not animate. I have tried placing CSS transition everywhere i could think it belonged, but when the jQuery adds on the class, the two affected pictures just jump.

**Background information:**
I am building a website, and as part of this website, a short animation is supposed to be played before .welcome slides to the side and the user is presented with the website / application underneath.

I am working with **bootstrap 3** as my framework and am using [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for these animations, along with my own .moveup.

I'm having extreme problems keeping my animation properly responsive, as soon as I change screen size, it gets broken in more ways than my poor little head can deal with.

**The animation:**
The animation is supposed to be 5 elements sliding up, *#ani_text_1*, *#ani_plus*, *#ani_text_2*, *#ani_equals* and *#ani_text_3*, in that order. Then 3 other elements, *#ani_mcloud*, *#ani_man* and *#ani_check*, slide down, whereafter *#ani_plus* and *#ani_equals*, slide further up between them, which finalizes the animation.

**My code:**
**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="welcome">
      <div class="animate col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="row ani_drawing">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">
            <img id="ani_mcloud" src="http://s33.postimg.org/5cnmfyam7/manycloud.png" class="wait_animation img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">
            <img id="ani_man" src="http://s33.postimg.org/v6strzl8f/man_indif2.png" class="wait_animation img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">
            <img id="ani_check" src="http://s33.postimg.org/v1p2ibdxb/check.png" class="wait_animation img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ani_text">
          <h4 id="ani_text_1" class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 wait_animation">Træk ikon og tekst der<br>passer bedst</h4>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <img id="ani_plus" src="http://s33.postimg.org/3tnmx8enz/plus.png" class="wait_animation img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
          <h4 id="ani_text_2" class="col-md-2 wait_animation">Flyt det over på<br>ham her</h4>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <img id="ani_equals" src="http://s33.postimg.org/syenane4f/equals.png" class="wait_animation img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
          <h4 id="ani_text_3" class="col-md-2 wait_animation">Få hjælp til at løse<br>din situation</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .animate {
        padding-top: 8%;
    }
    #ani_mcloud,
    #ani_check {
        padding-top: 30%;
    }
    .moveup {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 130px;
    }
    .welcome {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        left: -9px;
        background-color: @white;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
        -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
        transition: all 1.0s ease;
    }
    .blue {
        background-color: @darkred;
    }
    .wait_animation {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
        /** Chrome & Safari **/
        -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
        /** Firefox **/
        -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .animate img {
        width: 20%;
    }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.wbutton').on('click', function() {
  $(".welcome").toggleClass('blue');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ani_text_1").toggleClass("animation fadeInUp");
  }, 700);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ani_plus").toggleClass("animation fadeInUp");
  }, 900);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ani_text_2").toggleClass("animation fadeInUp");
  }, 1100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ani_equals").toggleClass("animation fadeInUp");
  }, 1300);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ani_text_3").toggleClass("animation fadeInUp").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ani_mcloud").toggleClass("animation fadeInDown");
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ani_cloud").toggleClass("animation fadeInDown");
      }, 700);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ani_plus").toggleClass("moveup");
      }, 900);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ani_man").toggleClass("animation fadeInDown");
      }, 1100);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ani_equals").toggleClass("moveup");
      }, 1300);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ani_check").toggleClass("animation fadeInDown");
      }, 1500);
    });
  }, 1500)
});
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link to the current functionality? It's somewhat difficult to assist without knowing what the desired outcome should be (visually).

Comment: Oh, of course I can, I have edited it in now, thank you for noticing me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're still waiting on a response here, I'll give you my take on the situation. I followed the link that was added, but don't think I saw an example of the Welcome animation that you're referring to on that page (possibly it's disabled at the moment, as I do see some of the markup). So it'll still be a little difficult to provide a more detailed answer.

To start with, I'll address your .moveup class animation on the #ani_plus element. It looks like the main target property is `bottom`. To ensure that the animation will work properly, a starting value must be present on the element before the animation actually affects it (it seems to be missing from that element at the moment). So add the following:

```
#ani_plus {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

That way, the transition knows from what initial value to animate from. A note on the above, it's a better practice to animate the element using the `transform` property, and leave it in its final position. Ideally, something like this:

```
#ani_plus {
  transform: translateY(10%);
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
}

.moveup {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

This is faster to render and, I think, easier to maintain (you don't have to worry about the final position).

Alright, and your original question: without knowing how the page is supposed to behave in responsive views, I can only recommend that you start with one element at a time, to avoid being overwhelmed. Decrease the viewport steadily until it starts looking ugly, then make an adjustment to that element. Rinse and repeat until things are looking perfect.

If you can fire up a fiddle to demonstrate the responsive issues, I'm more than willing to jump in and help debug / provide ideas. So let me know. Hopefully some of this was helpful anyway!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, your solution to my .moveup animation is correct and works, thank you very much for that. As for the link, it is the right one, you just have to click the 'Jeg er klar' button to start it, I am sorry that I forgot to add that, I will edit it in. I am very thankful that you gave me an answer despite not even being able to see the animation.